# Congruence Classes with Reals

Tags: number-theory

Can we say that (1/4 congruent to 2) mod 7? "because 4^5 congruent to 2"

If yes, does that mean 1/4 is member of congruence class [2] (mod 7)? what about 15/4,...?

What does that really mean?

Comment: It's a not particularly great way of expressing the fact that $4\times 2\equiv 1\pmod 7$.  It's clearer, I think, to write $4^{-1}\equiv 2 \pmod 7$.

Answer (score 0):

Since every nonzero element (class) has a multiplicative inverse modulo $7$ you can indeed think about things like $1/4$ or $3/5$ or $13/3$ mod $7$. Sometimes that's convenient, sometimes it's confusing.